# Python input().split() function issue

Tags: python

I need to take two numbers inputs from the user and then add these two numbers. so I use to take two numbers from user.

```
x,y = input().split()
```

But there are some instances where If a user enters only a single number, the program should print the same number. In the case if user enter only one number the error pops us that

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: You're next step in the journey learning Python is to learn about `try: ` and `except: `...https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Comment: May be your giving inputs like 12, if you want to split, give inputs like 1 2. There must be space in the values.

Answer (score 1):

It's not like that you need to check it after the input

```py
nums = input().split()
if len(nums) > 1:
    # Do stuff here
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

A reference on `try`/`except` - exception handling: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Your approach looks okay with taking user input and assigning to two vars. In the case where this fails, we know the user isn't following instructions so they can try again.

However, it's a rigid solution that only allows the user to input two values.  But if that's the case you want, you can catch the exception like this:

```
for _ in range(n_tries):
    try:
        x, y = input("Enter two numbers to add: ").split()

    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect input, try again.")
```

This makes it really easy: you don't have to test the length of the input and when it's right, it's automatically assigned into two variables.

If you want to be able to handle cases where the user gives only one number, three numbers, or whatever, then the assignment above won't work. You're better off assigning to one variable, and then writing code to test the length of the resulting list when you split the string.